# Returning result from API and displaying it using react

Tags: reactjs, return, state, react-props, webapi

I have a basic react app that I would like to display results from my API which is connected to my database.

I currently have a fetch method which calls my api, in the console I can see it has the correct data from the database, but I'm not sure how to display it in react, can you please help? I have the following code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function DisplayCases(props) {

  const [appState, setAppState] = useState({
    loading: false,
    repos: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setAppState({ loading: true });
  const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const url = "<my api url>" ;
fetch(proxyurl + url) 
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(contents => console.log(contents))
      .then((repos) => {
        setAppState({ loading: false, repos: repos });
      });
  }, [setAppState]);


  return (
      <div className='container'>
        <h1>Welcomme {props.location.state}, here are your open cases:</h1>
    <p> {appState.repos}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DisplayCases;
```

At the moment the

appState.repos doesnt display anything at all but the (contents => console.log(contents)) does contain the information I want to display ("cases" include customer forename customer surname etc) I want it to display like a list if thats possible.

Answer (score 0):

Best to only create another `.then` when an *asynchronous* action is occurring, otherwise you introduce more syntax noise and potential bugs like this one. Since `console.log` doesn't return anything, this section:

```
.then(contents => console.log(contents))
.then((repos) => {
  setAppState({ loading: false, repos: repos });
});
```

is passing on the return value of `console.log` to the next `.then`, which is `undefined`. Change to:

```
.then((repos) => {
  console.log(repos);
  setAppState({ loading: false, repos: repos });
});
```

Or, even better, remove the `loading` property entirely, and just check if `repos` exists or not instead, if you need to do so later.

```
const [repos, setRepos] = useState();
// ...
.then(res => res.json())
.then(setRepos)
.catch(handleErrors); // don't forget to handle errors
// ...

<p> {repos}</p>
```

Remember that functional component state should usually be separated out into individual variables when possible, if they relate to separate things - having a single master state variable instead is a bit of an antipattern.